# SecurityException when using ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork() (Android 11)

Tags: android

I am seeing crashes at Crashlytics for devices on android 11 when using the connectivity manager but I am unable to reproduce them.

I am creating the manager like so:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(context, CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            connectivityManager.requestNetwork(
                NetworkRequest.Builder().addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET).build(),
                networkCallback
            )
    }
```

and the crash logs are:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 10291
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
       at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.requestNetwork(IConnectivityManager.java:3503)
       at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3688)
       at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3838)
       at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3816)
```

All the permissions have been added in the manifest and I just don't see how the exception can be triggered.

Comment: any luck with this? I have a crash for "registerDefaultNetworkCallback".

Comment: I have the same problem @nayakasu. Have you solved it?

Comment: did you find any solution for it ?

Comment: I have the same problem. I can see some crashes in Crashlytics Let us know if you find the problem or know how to solve it.